# Dotnet Core How to pass HttpClient to ServiceModel?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

How would you pass custom HttpClient to ServiceModel class with constructor:

```
HelloServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
```

HelloServiceClient is generated by svcutil.  There was discussion on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2400) but it isn't directly related to ServiceModel.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I have a SOAP client (HelloServiceClient) which was generated by svcutil from server endpoint description.  I would like to pass custom HttpClient which implements a non-standard proxy to HelloServiceClient.  The scvutil generates object which can take two parameters: Binding and EndPoint.  My question is how do I pass HttpClient to the Binding?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a pre-configured HttpClient in the WCF client, first you need to create an EndpointBehavior that will obtain IHttpMessageHandlerFactory.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

public class CertificatePinningEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly Func<HttpMessageHandler> _httpHandler;

    public CertificatePinningEndpointBehavior(IHttpMessageHandlerFactory factory) 
    {
        _httpHandler = () => factory.CreateHandler();
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        bindingParameters.Add(new Func<HttpClientHandler, HttpMessageHandler>(handler => _httpHandler()));
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) { }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}
```

Then, add this behavior to he client with the appropriate messageHandler:

```
// dotnet host to manage dependencies and lifetime
using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient().ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(sp => sp.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => 
    { 
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
        // your config
        }
    }));
})
.UseConsoleLifetime().Build();

// later, use DI to get the IHttpMessageHandlerFactory
var httpMessageHandler = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpMessageHandlerFactory>()!;

var wsClient = new NumberConversionSoapTypeClient(new NumberConversionSoapTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration() { });

// Add the endpoint behavior to the client
wsClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CertificatePinningEndpointBehavior(httpMessageHandler));
```

Recently faced a very similar use case myself (certificate pinning): https://medium.com/@eduardpaul1091/certificate-pinning-in-net-8-when-using-wcf-web-service-reference-c-9e582f0e24bf

For more details read this post: https://dev.to/nikolicbojan/make-soap-requests-using-ihttpclientfactory-in-net-core-46hk